# ipad uitableview controller popover

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have a dynamically generated button on a detailviewcontroller (uisplitviewcontroller) that uses a uinavigation that when you tap will popover a uitableviewcontroller. The uitableviewcontroller pops up without any problems if I'm testint it with 0 sections. But when I change my section to 1 like so:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}
```

It would give this error:

> NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell
>   with identifier MatchCell - must register a nib or a class for the
>   identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

on this part:

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Also, I noticed that, **when stepping in the code** , it would go through the **numberOfSectionsInTableView** and **numberOfRowsInSection** more than once (usually twice or sometimes three times).

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you register a nib or class or connect a prototype cell in storyboard?

Comment: Hmm.. Not really sure how to connect a prototype cell. Isn't that only needed when you want to cutomize the cell's appearance?

Comment: could you post your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath implementation? what kind of cell do you use? not a custom one?